# R dplyr: How do I apply a less than / greater than mapping table across a large dataset efficiently?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a large dataset ~1M rows with, among others, a column that has a score for each customer record. The score is between 0 and 100.

What I'm trying to do is *efficiently* map the score to a rating using a rating table. Each customer receives a rating between 1 and 15 based the customer's score.

```
# Generate Example Customer Data
set.seed(1)
n_customers <- 10

customer_df <-
  tibble(id = c(1:n_customers),
         score = sample(50:80, n_customers, replace = TRUE))

# Rating Map
rating_map <- tibble(
  max = c(
    47.0,
    53.0,
    57.0,
    60.5,
    63.0,
    65.5,
    67.3,
    69.7,
    71.7,
    74.0,
    76.3,
    79.0,
    82.5,
    85.5,
    100.00
  ),
  rating = c(15:1)
)
```

The best code that I've come up with to map the rating table onto the customer score data is as follows.

```
customer_df <-
  customer_df %>%
  mutate(rating = map(.x = score,
                      .f = ~max(select(filter(rating_map, .x < max),rating))
                      )
         ) %>%
  unnest(rating)
```

The problem I'm having is that while it works, it is extremely inefficient. If you set *n = 100k* in the above code, you can get a sense of how long it takes to work.

```
customer_df

# A tibble: 10 x 3
      id score rating
   <int> <int>  <int>
 1     1    74      5
 2     2    53     13
 3     3    56     13
 4     4    50     14
 5     5    51     14
 6     6    78      4
 7     7    72      6
 8     8    60     12
 9     9    63     10
10    10    67      9
```

I need to speed up the code because it's currently taking over an hour to run. I've identified the inefficiency in the code to be my use of the purrr::map() function. So my question is how I could replicate the above results without using the map() function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
customer_df$rating <- length(rating_map$max) -  
           cut(score, breaks = rating_map$max, labels = FALSE, right = FALSE)
```

This produces the same output and is much faster. It takes 1/20th of a second on 1M rows, which sounds like >72,000x speedup.

It seems like this is a good use case for the base R `cut` function, which assigns values to a set of intervals you provide.

> cut divides the range of x into intervals and codes the values in x
> according to which interval they fall. The leftmost interval
> corresponds to level one, the next leftmost to level two and so on.

In this case you want the lowest rating for the highest score, hence the subtraction of the `cut` term from the length of the breaks.

*EDIT -- added `right = FALSE` because you want the intervals to be closed on the left and open on the right. Now matches your output exactly; previously had different results when the value matched a break.*

Comment: This was very helpful thank you! cut() works perfectly in this case. I kept looking for a tidyverse solution looking for a function like join_by and wasn't finding what I needed.

Comment: I'm surprised by this, but the findInterval method is even faster than 'cut', and both are much faster than the DT method.

Comment: OP also please double check that the cut is done correctly - it seems that "74" should be assigned 6 instead of 5? in which case you should change back to 'right = T'

Answer (score 1):

We could do a non-equi join

```
library(data.table)
setDT(rating_map)[customer_df, on = .(max > score), mult = "first"]
```

-output

```
     max rating    id
    <int>  <int> <int>
 1:    74      5     1
 2:    53     13     2
 3:    56     13     3
 4:    50     14     4
 5:    51     14     5
 6:    78      4     6
 7:    72      6     7
 8:    60     12     8
 9:    63     10     9
10:    67      9    10
```

---

Or another option in `base R` is with `findInterval`

```
customer_df$rating <- nrow(rating_map) - 
       findInterval(customer_df$score, rating_map$max)
```

-output

```
> customer_df
   id score rating
1   1    74      5
2   2    53     13
3   3    56     13
4   4    50     14
5   5    51     14
6   6    78      4
7   7    72      6
8   8    60     12
9   9    63     10
10 10    67      9
```